# Javascript validation with onsubmit function not working in IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, validation, onsubmit

I have a simple html form for which I want to validate the 2 inputs. The validation works fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and IE10. i.e. If I dont enter any values for plat and plng, the submit isnt executed in these browsers.

However in IE8 and IE7, the validation fails and I end up submitting the form and execute /php/search.php.

I am sourcing Jquery 1.8.3 on the page.

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" id="search-form-primary" action="/php/search.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input id="plat" name="plat" value="" type="text" >
    <input id="plng" name="plng" value="" type="text" >
    <button id="search" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var latt= $('#plat').val();
        var lngi = $('#plng').val();   
        if ((latt == "") || (lngi == "") || (latt == null) || (lngi == null))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
        }       
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure you want all of those double equals and not triple equals?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed them to "===" but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Maverick change <button id="search" type="submit"> to <input id="search" type="submit">

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for your input. I tried this but it doesnt seem to help.

Comment: @Maverick Its working dude, i checked on my system with IE 8

Comment: Okay I figured out what was going on. I have some other jquery scripts running on my page which seem to break the validation in IE8 and IE7. Once I removed the scripts my original code worked.. So did @shadow's suggestion. Thanks to everyone for your comments and help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `javascript:` in onsubmit for mainly IE browsers

for example

```
onsubmit="javascript:return validateForm();"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help. I still end up submitting the form in IE8 and IE7

Answer (score 0):

I usually make no submit button, but use javascript to submit the form. The form won't be submitted as long as javascript doesn't do so. for example:

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="textOnTheButton" onclick="ValidationFunction()"/>
```

Javascript

```
function ValidationFunction(){
    //validate the form here
    if(valid == true){
        document.getElementById('formName').submit();
    }
}
```

This has always worked for me...

Comment: Thanks for your response. This doesn't seem to work either. IE sucks!